# Is there a good algebraic model of random n-hypergraphs?

Tags: co.combinatorics, random-graphs, algebraic-combinatorics

Suppose $F$ is a finite field and $-1$ is a square in $F$. Let $E$ be the binary relation on $F$ where $(a,b) \in E$ iff $a - b$ is a square. Then $(F,E)$ is called a Paley graph. Paley graphs are well-known algebraic models of random graphs (indeed Paley graphs are ``quasi-random" in a precise sense).

I am curious to know if there is also a "finite field model" for random $n$-hypergraphs. It would be natural to ask for a quasi-random algebraic family of $n$-hypergraphs, but apparently there are multiple notions of quasi-randomness for hypergraphs, and I don't know anything about them, so I don't want to be more precise.

Comment: It is not clear what you are looking for. What properties of Paley graphs you want your hypergraphs to possess? Is there a specific application you have in mind? Otherwise, as currently written the question asks for a survey of a big field, which is not a good fit for MathOverflow.

Comment: Paley graphs form a quasi-random family. I would ask that the hypergraphs are quasi-random, but there are several non-equivalent notions of quasi-randomness for hypergraphs. So I want the hypergraphs to satisfy some reasonable notion of quasi-randomness. For example Conlon, Han, Person, and Schacht show in "Weak quasi-randomness for uniform hypergraphs" that several notions of quasi-randomness are equivalent. So I would be interested to know if there is a "finite field family" of hypergraphs that satisfies their notion, or any other reasonable notion, of quasi-randomness.

Comment: and by "finite field family" what I really mean is that the edge relation is defined by a first order formula in the language of fields, like how Paley graphs are defined by $\exists z \ne 0 (x - y = z^2)$.

Answer (score 2):

For $G$ a quasirandom hypergraph and $k \geq 3$, let $H$ be a hypergraph whose vertices are that of $G$ and $(x_1, ..., x_k)$ is a hyperedge iff $(x_1, ..., x_k)$ is a clique in $G$. Then there is a one-to-one correspondence between the hyperedges of $H$ and the $k$-cliques of $G$ and between the copies of $M_k$ in $H$ and the copies of $L(Q_k)$ in $G$, where $M_k$, a $k$-hypergraph with $k{2^{k-1}}$ vertices and $2^k$ edges, is defined on p.4 of the paper "Weak quasi-randomness for uniform hypergraphs" and $L(Q_k)$ is the line graph of the hypercube graph.

The $\text{MIN}_d$ condition, a quasi-random condition defined on p.5 of "Weak quasi-randomness for uniform hypergraphs", states that a sequence of hypergraphs is quasirandom if the density of a hyperedge (i.e. probability of finding a hyperedge by choosing $k$ vertices) tends to a fixed $d$ and the density of  $M_k$ tends to $d^{2^k}$.

The density of hyperedges on $H$ tends to $1/2^{k \choose 2}$ and the density of $M_k$ tends to $1/2^{{k \choose 2}2^k}$, by counting $k$-cliques and $L(Q_k)$ in the quasirandom graph $G$. Thus $H$ is quasidrandom if $G$ is.

So we can define such a class of $H$ by taking $G$ to be Paley graphs.

Comment: I think the exponents in your density formulas are off by a factor of $(k-1)/2$, i.e. some of the $k$s should be $\binom{k}{2}$.  One can use this idea to get a quasirandom hypergraph with density $c/2^{\binom{k}{2}}$ for any $c$ from $1$ to $2^k-1$, by using some Boolean formula in the conditions "$x_i - x_j$ is a perfect square" for $1\leq i < j \leq k$.

Comment: This is weaker than what I had in mind. I will try to explain why. This construction won't give something with the same first order properties as random hypergraphs, and in fact no construction of this form can. You construct a $k$-hypergraph $\mathcal{H}_k(G)$ from a graph $G$ such that $\mathcal{H}_k(G)$ is "weakly quasi-random" when $G$ is quasi-random. You do it in such a way that $\mathcal{H}_k(G)$ is first-order definable in $G$.

Comment: Let $H_k$ be the (unique up to isomorphism) countable random $k$-hypergraph. When $k = 2$ this is sometimes called the Erdos-Rado graph. Then $H_k$ satisfies a first order sentence $\varphi$ if and only if the probability that a random hypergraph satisfies $\varphi$ goes to $1$ as the cardinality goes to $\infty$. This is called a $0-1$ law. We can also characterize $H_k$ by saying that it is the unique countable graphs which satisfies certain "extension axioms". I won't state them but they are very reasonable.

Comment: Now, $\mathcal{H}_k(H_2)$ is not isomorphic to $H_k$. This is because we cannot interpret the random $k$-hypergraph in the random $\ell$-hypergraph when $k > \ell$.  There is no first order way to build $H_k$ in $H_\ell$. That may sound very esoteric but there is in fact a concrete combinatorial property called $\ell$-dependence that separates the two. I won't state it but it's natural.

Comment: Finitizing everything, it follows that there is a first-order definable property $P$ of $k$-hypergraphs such that a large random $k$-hypergraph has $P$ with probability going to $1$ and if $G$ is a random graph then $\mathcal{H}_k(G)$ does not have $P$ with probability going to $1$.

Comment: You can take $P$ to be of the following form (for some large enough fixed $n$): If $J$ is a sub hypergraph of $H$ with cardinality $n$ and $J^*$ is a hypergraph of cardinality $n + 1$ extending $J^*$ then there is an embedding $J^* \to H$ which is the identity on $J$, i.e. every possible one-point extension of an order $n$ sub hypergraph is realized in $H$. (this is the $n$th extension axiom).